# Support for openApi 3 in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

As cited in the documentation, "Google Cloud Endpoints supports APIs that are described using version 2.0 of the OpenAPI Specification." Are there any plans to support version 3.0 ?

Comment: Can you explain some of the benefits for 3.0? What do you want to do with Endpoints that you can't do with 2.0?

Comment: Almost 2022 and still not even OAS 3.0 ...

Comment: Google said its planned for Q1 2021. But no announcement yet.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is not an objective (fact-based) programming question. It is about project release cycles/schedules, which can only be answered by the company themselves.

Answer (score 7):

Cloud Support here! As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-overview) Cloud Endpoints support OpenAPI version 2.0.

I filed a feature request for a support of version 3.0. You can follow for the updates [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78271318).

Answer (score 6):

Until GCP supports version 3, you could use something like [apimatic.io](https://apimatic.io) to convert openapi v3 files to swagger (openapi 2) format.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, after 2 years there is something brewing on Google's side, you can read it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78271318). I guess they finally saw the need to upgrade Cloud Endpoints to support OpenAPI version 3.0. However, it is still not clear **when** they are going to release this, which I think is insane. Even M$ Azure API management supports version 3.0.